# Android App Widget with scrollable content similar to Google Offers app

Tags: android, android-widget, scroll

I'm creating a widget for my app, with several content sections, and I would like the user to be able to scroll through them in the home screen widget - not in a scrollable `TextView`, but with each paragraph as its own section, like the widget for the [Google Offers app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.offers):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like [a `StackView` widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html), available for app widgets as of API Level 11.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with that widget. :)