# Fetch Images from Gallery and display in Stackview widget

Tags: android, android-gallery, stackview

Multiple Image selection from gallery is almost done, am able to fetch the images I have selected, but am facing the problem to show the selected images in stack view,now am able to display the images in a linear layout, but I want to show the images in stack-view. kindly help me out please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the stackview you want here? Any sample provided ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868932/android-app-widget-with-scrollable-content-similar-to-google-offers-app

Comment: lol, you found the answer, why don't you just answer it and accept it yourself

Comment: hey its not the answer, i just wanted to show how the stackview looks.